# does django encode passwords in the Database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I created a user with a password `password123` but in the database the password field look like this `pbkdf2_sha256$260000$rJZWVrYXlokRG8fGMS1fek$S7Dm9soflUsy0Q74CJP8sB60tgfRWuRPdqj5XL0DBV0=`

- **the problem**: is when I create new user via rest framework i got the poassword feidl look like `passsword123`

1. so how should i created new user in order to keep the django password encoding functionality
2. also how to deactivate this password encoding functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses encryption middlewares to encrypt passwords (since the database sees passwords as VarChar fields, so Django's model sees them as plain text unless it is told otherwise). If you want the Django User model to use encryption, you must call

```
user_obj.set_password(passwd_text)
```

With this line of code, you tell Django to run encryption algorithms. For example, in your case, you can first use the serializer's extra_kwargs to exclude passwords from database-readable data, then create the user.

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop("password")
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

if you want to read more on Django users and passwords read these docs
[user model doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) and
[encryption types and password management doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/)

Answer (score 2):

you need to override `create` method in User Create Serializer:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = "__all__" # or your specific fields  
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
        }
```

Now your user password will be saved as hashed password in database.

Answer (score 1):

re. question 2.

Django does not store the password, only hashed value of the password, which it uses for comparison when the user logs in.

It is not possible to reverse engineer the password from this hash (well, mathematically it is possible, but you don't have the resources to run that process). Nor should it be.

If you wanted a password field that wasn't hashed, you would use just a string field. But... DON'T DO THIS! It is massively insecure.

There is no need for you to know the user's password.

As for question 1, I'm not sure why you're not seeing it hashed - you will need to post some code.

Comment: Django stores hash passwords in the database for security reasons  from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password

hashed_pwd = make_password("plain_text")
check_password("plain_text",hashed_pwd)  # returns True